# Default value should be zero html in

Tags: html, richfaces

I have a column that returns value from my backend but i dont want it to be called as soon as i start the system. I need the input field to be 0 by default till i click the button resetCountButton below. I tried to use "|| 0 in the value field but did not work as it gave an error cannot convert value Integer to boolean

```
*<rich:column id="countColumn">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="${msg['page.dfeOper082.count']}"/>       
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:inputText id="countField" value="#{DfeOper082MBean.dataModel.dfeOper082DataModel.map[virtual.id]}"
                                 disabled="#{virtual.firstDfeContractObject.quantity le 0}" converter="IntegerConverter"
                                 style="margin-left: initial; width: initial !important;" />
                </rich:column>
            </rich:dataTable>


            <a4j:commandButton id="resetCountButton" status="waitStatus" reRender="dfeoper082, DfeOper082ValidatePanel" action="#{DfeOper082MBean.resetCount}" value="${msg['page.dfeOper082.reset']}" style="float: right;" />*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the bean return 0 instead of trying to solve on client-side but you can also do this:

```
<h:outputText value="0" rendered="#{not bean.countReset}" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.count}" rendered="#{bean.countReset}" />
```